# Loop over "index table" to find out value of each row in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have two tables.

table AAA

```
userid exp
1      100
2      235325
3      3242
4      32543
```

table BBB

```
level  levelup_exp
1      10
2      100
3      1000
4      10000
5      100000
6      1000000
```

If I want to figure out user's level, I should loop over table BBB (ordered by level DESC), compare AAA.exp with BBB.levelup_exp, if exp is > than levelup_exp but <= than next levelup_exp, user's level is found.
So the output should be like this:

```
userid level
1      2
2      6
3      3
4      4
```

How can this be accomplished by using HiveQL?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution you can try and use userid , next_level as output, however your output is inconsistent

```
select userid , level, tab1.exp , levelup_exp  ,next ,next_level
 from tab1 as tab1 , (
select level,  levelup_exp
,lead(levelup_exp, 1) over (order by level) as next
,lead(level, 1) over (order by level) as next_level
 from tab2) as tab2x
where tab1.exp > levelup_exp  
 and tab1.exp <= next 
 order by userid
```